# SP 2016 Search not return data to file server (another domain)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, search-results, enterprise-search

In the Search Service Application I have create New Content Source "File Shares" \files.enter.com\documents (another domain), crawls worked successfully, but search returns nothing, why? What else do you need to configure so that data from a file server of another domain appears in the search?

[image]

Comment: Hi,@Fox, have you tried with an account which has enough permission on that file share? Also do all the files cannot be searched or only a part of them? What are the file types of these files?

Comment: Access rights, Word files, pdf...